# How to install PHP Extensionson SourceGuardian on wordpress docker image?

Tags: wordpress, docker, elementor

I am using docker to run Wordpress on my local machine. When I want to activate Elementor Pro on my wordpress site I get this error:

```
PHP script '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/abzarwp/abzarwp.php' is protected by SourceGuardian and requires a SourceGuardian loader 'ixed.7.2.lin' to be installed.

1) Click here to download the required 'ixed.7.2.lin' loader from the SourceGuardian site
2) Install the loader to /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
3) Edit and add 'extension=ixed.7.2.lin' directive
4) Restart the web server
```

My `docker-composer.yml` is like here:

```yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: poshasin_wp
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    networks:
      - poshasin_wp_net

    # ...
```

and, my wordpress `Dockerfile` is like here:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Now, how can I solve this problem? I mean how can I install `SourceGuardian` in wordpress docker image?

Comment: In Docker first you have to install that extension to available in php.ini. Are you doing same ?

Comment: Hi @aviboy2006, no. How can I do it?

Comment: https://linuxpitstop.com/install-sourceguardian-php-extension-on-ubuntu-linux/ first add same command in docker after your `RUN` command

Comment: https://github.com/davidalger/docker-images-php/blob/master/fpm-loaders/Dockerfile see this Dockerfile for reference

Comment: @aviboy2006, there is no `/etc/php7.2/mods-available/sourceguardian.conf` path in my container. What should I do?

Comment: Try second option which i shared. Check your php version path might be different.

Comment: @aviboy2006, in second option I got this error: `/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/php.d/15-sourceguardian.ini: Directory nonexistent`. I added this line `mkdir -p /etc/php.d/` but my problem didn't solve. What should I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I update my Wordpress `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.2-apache

# Install and enable Source Gaurdian loader
RUN PHP_VERSION=$(php -v | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d. -f1-2) \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/sourceguardian \
    && cd /tmp/sourceguardian \
    && curl -Os https://www.sourceguardian.com/loaders/download/loaders.linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && tar xzf loaders.linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && cp ixed.${PHP_VERSION}.lin "$(php -i | grep '^extension_dir =' | cut -d' ' -f3)/sourceguardian.so" \
    && echo "extension=sourceguardian.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/15-sourceguardian.ini \
    && rm -rf /tmp/sourceguardian
```

Now, everything is perfect!

Comment: great. what extra changes you made ?

Comment: Hi @aviboy2006 thank you for your helps. I changed this line `echo "extension=sourceguardian.so" > /etc/php.d/15-sourceguardian.ini` to `echo "extension=sourceguardian.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/15-sourceguardian.ini`

Comment: That what reference is correct only you have to check path

Comment: Yes! I only changed the path.